# Determine the highest and lowest number

Tags: java

I'm currently writing a program where the user must input 10 numbers and then the output will be the highest number and the lowest number. There is something wrong in my code but couldn't find it.

```
int highest=0, lowest=0, num=0;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number:");
    num = scan.nextInt();
}

if (num > highest) {           
    highest = num;
}         
else if(num < lowest) {             
    lowest = num;
}

System.out.println("Highest number is: " + highest);
System.out.println("Lowest number is: " + lowest);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Initialise your values differently:

```
int highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

If you initialise them both to zero, you will never have a "highest" value below zero, or a "lowest" value above zero

Comment: Is there another way around of achieving the answer without using  Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Comment: Why don't you want to use those values? Well, you could always inline them ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You should put your two `if` conditions in the `for` loop else you will only compare the last number. And lowest shouldn't be set to 0 but to Integer.MAX_VALUE

Answer (score 3):

You have some issues with your initialization and your logic:

```
int highest=Math.MIN_VALUE;
int lowest=Math.MAX_VALUE;
int num=0;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


for(int i=0; i<10; i++){

   System.out.print("Enter a number:");
   num = scan.nextInt();
   if (num > highest){

    highest = num;
   }

   if(num < lowest){

    lowest = num;
   }

}



   System.out.println("Highest number is: " + highest);
   System.out.println("Lowest number is: " + lowest);
```

You should also use 2 `if` conditions rather than an `else if`. If you have only one number, chances are that you will end up with something similar to `highest` being equal to some digit you entered while `lowest` will still be equal to `Math.MAX_VALUE`. This can cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You are implicitly assuming that lowest and largest are 0, that might now be the case,
try this code snippet..

```
class Main{
        public static void main(String args[]){
                int highest=0, lowest=0, num=0;
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                highest = lowest = scan.nextInt();
                for(int i=1; i<10; i++){
                       System.out.print("Enter a number:");
                       num = scan.nextInt();
                       if (num > highest){
                           highest = num;
                       }
                       if(num < lowest){
                           lowest = num;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Highest number is: " + highest);
                    System.out.println("Lowest number is: " + lowest);
               }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this code what is going on?